# Fetch pending forever because of adblock

Tags: javascript, fetch

My fetch statement is stuck on pending when using adblock

I've tried other browsers and it works but when I try using chrome fetch gets stuck on pending because of my adblock.

```
fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(() => console.log('success')).catch(() => console.log('fail'));
```

EDIT: so I've been told that this is because the link I am using looks like an ad, and that I should change it. But I'm using the provided web app link for google sheets so I'm not sure I can change it.

EDIT: I fixed it, had to rewrite it as

```
fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', mode: 'no-cors', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(() => console.log('success')).catch(() => console.log('fail'));
```

the url went against the CORS policy so changing the mode allowed me to bypass it.

Comment: solution: remove adblock

Comment: Or add an adblock exception?

Comment: @JaromandaX That's not a practical solution if they want other people to be able to use the code.

Comment: Maybe change the URL so it doesn't look like it's going to an advertising site.

Comment: I'm posting data to a google sheet so I'm using the provided web app url so I'm not sure I can change it.